# (FES EDD) New vendor submission page is blank

Tags: plugins, themes, pages, templates

When someone signups as a vendor and tries to post a new submission(service), when its posted the page is blank: https://markety.gg/downloads/demo-from-dilip

In the backend, the submission is automatically approved in the backend as seen here, it's live!

[image]

[image]

I am so lost of direction, everything is there but why the page is blank?